# I am trying to add a class to a li tag that has a class of disabled

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

How do write a JavaScript conditional statement:

```
If an li tag has a class of "disabled" then add a class of "hide"
```

I am trying to add that class to an li tag that has this class. The li tag does not have an id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to get all `li` tags:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Then loop over them and perform the action:

```
for(var i = lis.length; i--;) {
    var li = lis[i];
    if(/\bdisabled\b/.test(li.className)) {
        li.className += ' hide';
    }
}
```

**Reference:** [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className)

*Why can't we use `getElementsByClassName`?*

Because it is [not supported up to and including IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).

---

But you could make a test whether the browser supports [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
if(typeof document.querySelectorAll === 'function') {
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li.disabled');
    for(var i = lis.length; i--;) {
        lis[i].className += ' hide';
    }
}
else {
    // code from above
}
```

---

If you just have a reference to some `li` you only use the if class:

```
if(/\bdisabled\b/.test(element.className)) {
    element.className += ' hide';
}
```

*(In all cases, you could also add a further test to check whether the elements already have the `hide` class.)*

---

**Update:**

In case you want to remove that class again, you can make a similar loop and use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
for(var i = lis.length; i--;) {
    var li = lis[i];
    li.className = li.className.replace(/\s*hide\s*/, '');
}
```

You should consider to make the add and remove class functions reusable so that you can use them with other classes too.

Comment: Use a space: li.className += ' hide';

Comment: querySelectorAll isn't much better: *Currently supported in FF3.1+, IE8+ (only in IE8 standards mode), and Safari 3.1+* (*ref.* [JS functions](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml))

Comment: @Brad Christie: That is why I said one has to test first, whether `querySelectorAll` is available. If it is, it will probably be faster. @Lee: Just fixed it when you wrote your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('li.disabled').addClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like jQuery:

```
$('li').hasClass('disabled').addClass('hide');
```

(explicitly mention [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) just for reference sake and clarity, though `li.disabled` works just as well).

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var item = items[i];
    if (/\bdisabled\b/.test(item.className)){
        item.className += ' hide';
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `getElementsByTagName` and note that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported before IE9.

Comment: Yeah I am getting js errors because that function is not recognized.

Comment: @FelixKling & @Amen: Fixed. My apologies, spoiled by jQuery these days. (Though I'll probably just redact the answer since FelixKling adequately answered it)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, ALL disabled LI elements need a class of hide?  Can you not edit the CSS and hide them like that?  Or use JavaScript to add a class to the HTML or BODY element and then in CSS, e.g.:

HTML.hide-disabled LI.disabled {/* properties to hide these elements */}

Comment: Of course I could do that. But that is not what I am asking. I have a select list. And when someone chooses and a tag withing that list wheter it by a li or option tag a class of disabled it being added. What I want to do is add an additional class of hide dynamically

Comment: OK, just saying, that's the long way...  That's all.